# Printing file starting from matched line

Tags: shell

Suppose there's a file with a structure like this

```
Useless line 1
Useless line 2
===USEFUL STUFF STARTS HERE===
Useful line 1
...
```

How can I print all the lines after the first line that matches arbitrary pattern?

Comment: Which OS? Which shell?

Answer (score 0):

For Linux, Bash:

```
{ grep -m 1 "===USEFUL STUFF STARTS HERE===" > /dev/null && cat ;} < input_file
```